# Symfony does not show private services in debug:container --show-private

Tags: php, symfony

Running

```
app/console debug:container --show-private
```

does not list the services declared with `public: false` e.g:

```
 another_service:
        public: false
        class: MineBundle\Service\FirstService
```

But, If I run `app/console debug:container --show-private | wc -l` and `app/console debug:container | wc -l` I will get different results.

Tried with symfony 2.8 and 3.1 and got same behaviour.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Stupidly obvious but have you made sure that your service file is being loaded and that you have cleared the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sorry, it's in the doc :)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#debugging-services)

> If a private service is only used as an argument to just one other
>   service, it won't be displayed by the debug:container command, even
>   when using the --show-private option. See Inline Private Services for
>   more details.

then

> What makes private services special is that, if they are only injected
>   once, they are converted from services to inlined instantiations (e.g.
>   new PrivateThing()). This increases the container's performance.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. Guess I was too stuck into thinking this is just a visibility control thing when in fact is there to optimize the container. :)